# Why jquery no work with route parameter in laravel 8?

Tags: jquery, laravel, routes

In my laravel application I create a route parameter. My route is:

```
Route::get('/BinCard/{steak}',[BinCardController::class, 'Index']);
```

Here I generated different URL like:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/BinCard/A-1(f)
http://127.0.0.1:5000/BinCard/A-2(f)

Here A-1(f) and A-2(f) is my steak parameter.

But when I want to use jquery, then Jquery is not working with my view. Here is my controller and view.

Controller:

```
function Index($steak){


        $buyer_data=BinFabricModel::select('buyer_name')
            ->where('steak_name','=',$steak)
            ->where('balance','>',0)
            ->groupBy('buyer_name')
            ->get();
        $buyer=substr($buyer_data,16,-3);

        $style_data=BinFabricModel::select('style_name')
        ->where('steak_name','=',$steak)
        ->where('balance','>',0)
        ->groupBy('style_name')
        ->get();
    $style=substr($style_data,16,-3);

    $po_data=BinFabricModel::select('po_name')
        ->where('steak_name','=',$steak)
        ->where('balance','>',0)
        ->groupBy('po_name')
        ->get();
    $po=substr($po_data,13,-3);
    $receive_date_data=BinFabricModel::select('receive_date')
        ->where('steak_name','=',$steak)
        ->where('balance','>',0)
        ->groupBy('receive_date')
        ->get();
    if (strlen($receive_date_data)==31){
        $receive_date=substr($receive_date_data,18,-3);
    }
    elseif (strlen($receive_date_data)==53){
        $receive_date=substr($receive_date_data,40,-3);
    }
    else{
        $receive_date='we';
    }
    $created_date_data=BinFabricModel::select('created_at')
        ->where('steak_name','=',$steak)
        ->where('receive_date','=',$receive_date)
        ->groupBy('created_at')
        ->get();
    $created_date=substr($created_date_data,16,-3);
    $sum=BinFabricModel::where('steak_name',$steak)->where('created_at','=',$created_date)->sum('qty');
    $sumIssue=BinFabricModel::where('steak_name',$steak)->where('receive_date','=',$receive_date)->sum('out_qty');
    $sumBalance=BinFabricModel::where('steak_name',$steak)->where('balance','>',0)->where('created_at','=',$created_date)->sum('balance');


    $SteakData=json_decode(BinFabricModel::where('steak_name','=',$steak)
        ->where('created_at','=',$created_date)
        ->where('buyer_name','=',$buyer)
        ->where('po_name','=',$po)
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(100)->get());
    return view('BinCard',compact('SteakData','sum','sumIssue','sumBalance','buyer','style','po','receive_date','created_date'));
}
```

My View:

```
@extends('Layout.app')
@section('content')

    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <section class="d-none">
        <div class="bin-card--table-section">
            <div class="card bincard">
                <div class="card-header mainheader">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                  

  <!-- //new flex 23.10.21-->
                    <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
                        <!-- //add add flex  23.10.21  -->
                        <h1>BIN CARD  <small class="subheader">Rackwise</small></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>Friends Knittings LTD.</h1>
                    <h3>South Salna,Gazipur</h3>
                    <div class="p-2"><span style="float: right;"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="font-size: 100px"></i> </span>
                        <br><br><img style="float: right;" alt="QrCode" src="./RackwiseItemlive_files/chart" &choe="UTF-8">
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <br>
                            <center>
                                <table class="tgm text-center" border="2px">
                                    <thead>
                                    <th class="tgm-baqh" colspan="2"><span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 20px;">{{ Request()->steak }}<br>
                                            SH</span></th>
                                    <th class="tgm-baqh" colspan="20"><span style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder;font-size: 20px;">BIN CARD</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tgm-0laxx" colspan="8"><strong>{{$buyer}}</strong><br>
                                            Style: {{$style}}<br>
                                            PO: {{$po}}<br>
                                            Item: <br>
                                            <!-- Dimension: 57 INCH -->
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="tgm-0laxx" colspan="9">
                                            <strong>Supplier: KUNSHAN HUAYUE TEXTILE AND GARMENTS CO.LTD</strong><br>
                                            Order by: Friend's Knittings<br>
                                            Receivedate: {{$receive_date}}<br>
                                            Inputdate: {{$created_date}}<br>
                                            Lot: 1ST LOT,15-SEP-2021 </td>
                                        <td class="tgm-0laxx" colspan="9">
                                            <strong>Constraction: 109861</strong><br>
                                            Total Fabric: {{$sum}}YDS<br>
                                            Issue: {{$sumIssue}}<br>
                                            <span style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">Balance: </span> <span style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">{{$sumBalance}} YDS</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <br><br><br><br>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">#<br></td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Barcode</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Roll#</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Shade</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Width/GSM </td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Color</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Recvd
                                            Qty</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Issue Date</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Issue
                                            QTY</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Balance</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr">Unit</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-fymr" colspan="3">Sign</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    @php
                                        $i=1;
                                    @endphp
                                    @foreach($SteakData as $SteakData)

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$i}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->barcode}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->roll}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->shade_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->dimension_name}}/-</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->color_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->qty}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->qty}}</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>{{$SteakData->out_qty}}</td>
                                        <td>YDS</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tgm-0laxx" colspan="9">Prepared by</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-lqy6l" colspan="9">Store Officer</td>
                                        <td class="tgm-lqy6l" colspan="8">Store Manager</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                            </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
</section>
<!-- main content end -->




<!-- main content -->
<section id="twoSecId" class="">
    <div class="inventory-table-section">
        <div class="card maincard">
            <div class="card-header mainheader">
                <center><h1>Bin Card <h4>(Rack-Wise) </h4> </h1></center>
            </div><br>
            <div id="goodReceiveCardDivId" class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>{{ Request()->steak }}</h3>
                        <h3>Buyer: {{$buyer}}</h3>
                        <h3>Style: {{$style}}</h3>
                        <h3>PO: {{$po}}</h3>
                        <h3>PO: {{$receive_date}}</h3>
                        <h3>PO: {{$created_date}}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="demo">ryhrthuyjreyhre</div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Total Received: {{$sum}}</h3>
                        <h3>Issue: {{$sumIssue}}</h3>
                        <h3><button type="button" class="btc1" id="detailsRackId">{{$sumBalance}}</button></h3>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <h3>Cartoon:</h3>
                        <h1>{{$currentURL = url()->current()}}</h1>
                    </div> </div>
            </div></div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="vbt"></button>
    <input type="text" id="vtn">

</section>
<section>
    efwef
</section>
```

@endsection

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var options={
                // render method: 'canvas', 'image' or 'div'
                render: 'canvas',

                // version range somewhere in 1 .. 40
                minVersion: 1,
                maxVersion: 40,

                // error correction level: 'L', 'M', 'Q' or 'H'
                ecLevel: 'L',

                // offset in pixel if drawn onto existing canvas
                left: 0,
                top: 0,

                // size in pixel
                size: 200,

                // code color or image element
                fill: '#000',

                // background color or image element, null for transparent background
                background: null,

                // content
                text: 'no text',

                // corner radius relative to module width: 0.0 .. 0.5
                radius: 0,

                // quiet zone in modules
                quiet: 0,

                // modes
                // 0: normal
                // 1: label strip
                // 2: label box
                // 3: image strip
                // 4: image box
                mode: 0,

                mSize: 0.1,
                mPosX: 0.5,
                mPosY: 0.5,

                label: 'no label',
                fontname: 'sans',
                fontcolor: '#000',

                image: null
            }
            $('#demo').qrcode(options);
        });
```

As I am a beginner. Seeking help to the community.
I use jquery in the right way and check many times.

Comment: Nothing in your browser console? Did you load jQuery in your layout?

Comment: I extend my view with @extends('Layout.app'). And my jquery is here.